# How can I use Future builder with provider?

Tags: flutter, dart

My main objective is to show a `CircularProgressIndicator` before I get a location address `placename` but I keep getting this error  `The getter 'placeName' was called on null.`.I did try to check the `null` value in `futureBuilder` but I believe my implementation is wrong. Could you please take a look ?
This is my `AppData` class

```
class AppData extends ChangeNotifier {
 Address pickUpLocation;
 void updatePickUpLocationAddress(Address pickUpAddress) {
    pickUpLocation = pickUpAddress;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and this is the `Address` class

```
class Address {
  String placeFormattedAddress;
  dynamic placeName;
  String placeId;
  double latitude;
  double longitude;

  Address(
      {this.placeFormattedAddress,
      this.placeName,
      this.placeId,
      this.latitude,
      this.longitude});
}
```

Now in my `MainScreen` I am using it like this but the error persisting.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
\\\
body: Stack( 
\\\
Flexible(
    child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
            FutureBuilder (
                future: Provider.of < AppData > (context)
                .pickUpLocation
                .placeName,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.data == null) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    } else {
                        return Text(
                            Provider.of < AppData > (context)
                            .pickUpLocation
                            .placeName,

                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            
                        );
                    }
                }),
          
        ],
    ),
)
```

Comment: have a look at how I combined the features of FutureProvider & ChangeNotifierProvider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533330/how-to-combine-features-of-futureprovider-futurebuilder-waiting-for-async-data

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few things to be aware of.

1. Your `Future`... isn't really a Future. You're just evaluating a synchronous property of your `AppData` Object provided by your Provider... and that's really it. Therefore the `FutureBuilder` should immediately evaluate its expression without giving that "loading" experience (it should render the "loaded" widget after a first rebuild).
2. Say you're using a `Provider` to return the `Future` you're looking for (and that's ok), which is something close to your implementation: something like that is erroneous since it would "stress" your widget tree with handling two state changes (the provider changing and/or the future being completed). Furthermore, *your future gets fired every time you rebuild this Widget*: that's not good (usually, firing a Future multiple times means asking your backend for the same data multiple times).

To fix your situation you have to:

1. Let your getter properly return and handle a `Future`;
2. Initialize the call to your getter (i.e. the Future call) *before* you call the build method.

Here's how I'd change your provider model/class:

```
class AppData extends ChangeNotifier {
 Address? pickUpLocation;

 Future<void> updatePickUpLocationAddress() async {
    // TODO: Maybe add error handling?
    var pickUpLocation = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));  // Request mock
    
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Now, to initialize the Future you either do so in the above Provider (in the Constructor of `AppData`), or you have to change your Widget to be `Stateful` so that we can access to the `initState()` method, in which we can initialize the Future without worrying about multiple calls. In your (now `Stateful`) Widget:

```
var myFuture;
// ...
void initState() {
  myFuture = Provider.of<AppData>(context).updatePickUpLocationAddress();
}
// ...
Widget build (BuildContext context) {
  return // ...
         FutureBuilder(
           future: myFuture, // already initialized, won't re-initalize when build() is called
           builder: (ctx, snapshot) => // ...
}
```

That should be it for this Provider + Future pattern, **although a final consideration should be mentioned**.

Take this [made up example](https://dartpad.dev/d0d3917206461520aeb501411cd7e214) and look what happens (i.e. read the console) when you fire the `tap` some times: if `ChildWidget1` is disposed, then `myFuture` will be fired again when it gets re-loaded in the tree. This happens because `ChildWidget1` is entirely removed from the tree and then re-added again to it, i.e. it's disposed and re-initialized.

This is useful to remember because having a `StatefulWidget` doesn't mean we are "immune" from side effects like this one.

Comment: Thanx, I will accept your answer However this is what Ive done

Comment: Thank you! I've seen your answer, you probably didn't need a `Future`, then ;-) You did the right thing!

Comment: Don't forget to add listen:false to your provider in initState(), otherwise it will be triggered at each change!

Answer (score 1):

```
Flexible(
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
                if (Provider.of < AppData > (context)
                    .pickUpLocation ==
                    null)
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),

                    if (Provider.of < AppData > (context)
                        .pickUpLocation !=
                        null)
                        Text(
                            Provider.of < AppData > (context)
                            .pickUpLocation
                            .placeName,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),  
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is facing this problem
You can easily click on Options+enter on Mac and click on "wrap with Builder"
then just pass the context to your future function

```
 child: Builder(
                builder: (context) {
                  return FutureBuilder(
                      future: futureFunctionHere(context),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
```